# Как на свет появился "ребёнок"?

Tags: этимология

**Кот**ёнок, **лис**ёнок, **слон**ёнок, **льв**ёнок... А от кого произошёл **реб**ёнок?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По статье этимологического словаря Фасмера слово "ребенок" произошло от "раб".

А вот слово "дитя" имеет отношение к кормлению грудью: Праслав. *de№te§,* de№tь. Форма на -i- в первом слоге исключительно вост.-слав., вероятно, результат ассимиляции *дkтина; см. Фортунатов (KZ 36, 51) против Розвадовского (RS 2, 111). Эти слова восходят к и.-е.* dhЊiё- "кормить грудью, сосать"; см. доиґть, доюґ. Ср. др.-инд. dhЊnuґs· ж. "дойная корова", авест. daЊnu- "самка животного" с и.-е. oi, но ср. также лит. de†le†~ "пиявка", pirm-   de†le†~ "корова, отелившаяся впервые", др.-инд. dhѓґtavЊ "сосать", aґdhѓt "сосал", греч. q»sato "сосал",      qhl» "материнская грудь", лат. fЊlѓre "сосать", fЊmina "женщина", ирл. diґnim "сосу"; см. Бернекер 1, 196;   Траутман, BSW 51; В. Шульце, KZ 27, 425, Мейе, MSL 14, 348.   (Этимолог. словарь М. Фасмера)

А "детвора" по Фасмеру от "детва" - "пчелиный выводок" .

Получается, что с детьми одни сложности: эти три слова имели изначально мало общего.

Зато слово "жеребенок"  родственно греч. brљfoj ср. р. "плод, новорожденный, ребенок, детеныш", возм., др.-инд. gaґrbhas "материнское чрево, плод во чреве", авест. garЌva- - то же; см. Уленбек, Aind. Wb. 78; Цупица, GG 77; Траутман, BSW 87; Буазак 133.

Comment: Это уже не ответ, а просто хочется поделиться. На украинском языке младенцы - немовлята (я так понимаю, что имеется в виду "неразговаривающие"), дети чуть старше, малыши - малюки или малята, а подростки - пiдлiтки.

Comment: >На украинском языке младенцы - немовлята (я так понимаю, что имеется в виду "неразговаривающие")

Да. Те, которые *не молвят*, не могут молвить, укр. *не можуть мовити*. +1 за ответ.

Comment: В украинском языке вообще много метких слов. А самым метким я считаю слово "нежить" — "насморк". Ну как еще иначе это гадость назовешь?)))))))

Comment: Маленькое замечание. Некоторые шрифты на компьютере не могут отображать редко встречающиеся символы. Тех. подробности тут, я думаю, не интересны. Поэтому на экране может отображаться такой вот сумбур, как в Вашем ХОРОШЕМ (подчёркиваю) ответе выше.

>Праслав. de№te§, de№tь.

Я когда копирую из какого-нибудь словаря в свой ответ, стараюсь проверять, чтобы это было читаемо.

Comment: А символ "звёздочка" ( * ) на ЭТОМ форуме используется для разметки текста: курсив, жирный. Я тоже стараюсь проверить. 

Потому что звёздочка также иногда используется В СЛОВАРЯХ, чтобы обозначить, что слово (или корень) -- из реконструированного праязыка и ПРЕДПОЛОЖИТЕЛЬНО выглядело/звучало таким образом. Например, русс. слово *город* от праславянского *gordъ. 

Когда копируешь из словаря на этот форум, да ещё выделяешь здесь текст, может получиться не то, на что рассчитывал.

Comment: Спасибо, постараюсь впредь обращать на это внимание.

Comment: Насморк точно "нежить" :)

Answer (score 2):

Слово "робя" я читала в худ. произведениях, так что форма "ребенок" аналогична другим приведенным.  Правда, я воспринимаю это слово как множественное число.
Прочитала, что "робя" первоначально означало "раб"... Ну, может быть...

Answer (score 2):

Из ПИЕ ***o̯orbhos*** "сирота". Отсюда же "работник" и "раб". Изначальное значение - тот, кто находится рядом, крутится вокруг (родственное слово - "орбита" от ПИЕ ***o̯orbhis*** "круг, шар").

Answer (score 1):

Всё верно концовка-(юк,ёк, ок) указывает на малую частицу,.(.ён,ен,ИН)-откуда исходит,(чей).,реб,роб-на работника????,но не так всё просто.РЕБЁНОК ,скорей всего ,это ТЪРЭБЕНОК-требующий,просящий,ТЕРЕБящий титьку..Со временем глухой звук( т)слился с Р.(моё тупое предположение)

Comment: Очень тупое

Comment: Откуда чадо появляется? Из уТъРОБЫ материнской,пэтому и " требунок",аналогично-жребенок,ягненок,барвинок...ЖИВОТ матери=УТРЭБА,от этого-требуха.

Answer (score 0):

Из санскрита: arbha, garbha - ребенок, sagarbha - беременная (женщина). 
Древний корень "рб", обозначающий УЗЫ, СВЯЗЬ, присутствует в словах серб, сорб, сябры, присербиться (пристать к компании), веревка. В болгарских върба (ива), връв (шнур), врабче (воробей - смысл: "присоседившийся"). В сербских врпца (шнур, лента), бубна врпца (барабанное сплетение). В украинских пасерб (пасынок), пасербица (падчерица). В древнеславянском РЪВНЦА (веревочка). Верба у славян считалась богиней чадородия. Так что, робя имеет смысл свой (родной) парень, а совсем не раб. А ребенок - это маленький родственник (соплеменник).

Answer (score -1):

Ребенок-русское слово ,и присхождение слова ,то же русское..,т,к наш язык очень древен,то искажение в первоначальном произношении вполне реально.Санскритская формула лишь подтверждает правильность формулы-..трэ=рэ,ре...требовать=реветь,трепать.,труба=рува,рупор,труха=руха,трусить=рушить,трепать=рвать,репать,репей,порепанный=потрепанный=поръванный...,этих примеров перехода тре в ре и обратно тысяча и есть этому объяснение..Поэтому :Ребенок-это тот же ревунок=требунок из утробы.

Comment: Каким образом "санскритская формула" подтверждает, что ребенок - "русское слово"?

Comment: Ваш язык очень древен.

Comment: Неужели настолько "древен", что Вы так и не освоили азы пунктуации?  Ну а по сути... Вы как предпочитаете "с потолка" или "из пальца"? Серьезно относиться к заявлениям "из утробы"  не приходится.

Comment: Зачем копать до санскрита. Вот, всё в том же библейском языке, корень "РБ" означает множество, размножение. До "РеБёнка" ещё далеко, но в этом что-то есть, имхо.